# Docker Container/AWS EC2 Public DNS Refusing to Connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, docker, dns

I am unable to connect to my EC2 instance via its public dns on a browser, even though for security groups "default and "launch-wizard-1" port 80 is open for inbound and outbound traffic.

It may be important I note that I have a docker image that is running in the instance, one I launched with:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 elasticsearch
```

I'm under the impression this forwards port 80 of the container to port 80 of the EC2 instance, correct?

Comment: Are you running in a vpc?

Comment: Thanks for the help! Yes it's in a vpc

Comment: The instance is in private or public subnet?

Comment: How can I check whether it's private or public?

Comment: Check the instance subnet, and the check the subnets defined in the VPC.

Comment: You should be able to check this if you have access to aws console

Comment: There are three subnets defined in the VPC, all of them have route tables with "local" targets. Does this mean they are private?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenarios.html  .. confirm which vpc type you have?

Comment: unless the instance is in private subnet they should get a public subet..

Comment: From what I see in the docs, I'm in scenario 1, as I have no VPNs or NATs  created or running. However, the EC2 instance does not have an elastic IP, which according to the docs means that it cannot connect to the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that elasticsearch serves http over port 9200.
So the correct command was:

```
docker run -d -p 80:9200 elasticsearch
```

The command was run under root.

Comment: Port 9300 is also listed in the elasticsearch documentation, so a better command would probably be: 


     docker run -d -p 80:9200 -p 8080:9300 elasticsearch